# Start axis points at 1 in ggplot2 R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe in R in 7 columns with 1st column used as X axis and rest of the 6 columns used as Y axis. The x axis has numbers from 1 to 1200. The values in the rest of the 6 columns varies from 0 to the maximum upto 12000

[image]

I am trying to plot a line for this dataframe using ggplot2.

Here's the code I have so far

```
mynewframe <- merge_recurse(file.list,all.x=TRUE, all.y=TRUE, by="ElNumber") 
mynewframe[is.na(mynewframe)] <- 0
sortedDF <- mynewframe[order(mynewframe$ElNumber), ]
library(ggplot2)
sortedDF.melted <- melt(sortedDF, id.vars = "ElNumber")
p_lines <- ggplot(sortedDF.melted, aes(as.numeric(ElNumber), value, col = variable)) + geom_line() 
xbreaks.vec <- seq(min(sortedDF.melted$ElNumber), max(sortedDF.melted$ElNumber), by = 100)
p_lines + scale_x_continuous(breaks = xbreaks.vec)
```

I can not change the value of x and y axis to start from 1. I want to generate a graph like this.

[image]

How can I change the scale_x_continuous and scale_y_continuous to plot all 6 columns as a line graph.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```r
p_lines + 
scale_x_continuous(breaks = xbreaks.vec, limits = c(1,12000)) +
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(1,12000)
```

You may want to set breaks in some logical way.